# Data Type Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm a beginner in angular test with jasmine and i need to test data type(e.g. String, int, etc.)

This is my controller, my data is instantiated to null and later it will be a string :

```
_this.instance = {
      template_fields: {
        guid: null
      }
}

// It becomes string
<input type="radio" ng-model="prCreateCtrl.instance.template_fields.guid" value="{{template.guid}}" required>
```

This is my test :

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($state, $controller, $rootScope, $q) {
    state = $state.get('app.provision');
    ctrl = $controller('ProvisionCreateCtrl', {
      instance: {
        template_fields: {
          guid : {}
        }
      }
    });
}));

it('should resolve data', function () {
  expect(ctrl.instance.template_fields.guid instanceof String).toBeTruthy();
});
```

I don't understand when should I give a String and how can I test it. Is using instanceof String the right way ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use `jasmine.any()` function.

In your case, inside `it()` block:

`expect(ctrl.instance.template_fields.guid).toEqual(jasmine.any(String));`

Comment: thanks but i have an error :  Expected null to equal <jasmine.any(String)> because guid : {} but i don't know when i need to declare guid with a string to test it, like this : guid : "d5ccabfa-11e5-a0d0-0687df08e4e5" ?

Comment: Yes, you should have some string to test your variable with. If `guid` is a string, then add some string for testing as you mentioned.

Comment: but where i add some string to guid to test it ??

Comment: In your `beforeEach()` block. In place of `guid:{}`, write `guid:'someString'`

Comment: when i replace guid:{} with guid:'some string' in beforeEach() i have this error : Expected null to equal <jasmine.any(String)> guid is null.

Comment: That is because you are setting `guid` to null in your controller. Since it is a test, you will not be able to enter something in your `<input>` tag. So you can manually set `ctrl.instance.template_fields.guid = 'someString` in your `it()` block before the `expect()` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `toBeInstanceOf` matcher:

Inside `it()` block:

`expect(ctrl.instance.template_fields.guid).toBeInstanceOf(String);`

I think it's simple & makes your test more readable. Have fun :)